# Pyspark pivot with Dynamic columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have Pyspark Dataframe as follows,

[image]

I am pivoting  the data based Month and T columns and need to produce the following output.

[image]

There are some quarters like q2,q3,q4 are not present in T column but i need to fill them with null values.It should be dynamic and these quarters should be in latest order like q4 2023 will be first then q3 2023,q2 2023,q1 2023 etc...

I amusing the following pyspark code

```
FinalDF = df.groupBy("id","month").pivot("T").agg(
   F.first("Oil"),
   F.first("Gas"),
)
```

Comment: you can use the `values` optional parameter to pass the list of quarters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `values` optional parameter of `pivot()` to pass the desired list of quarters.

here's an example

```py
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('id', 'month'). \
    pivot('t', values=['q1 2023', 'q2 2023', 'q3 2023', 'q4 2023']). \
    agg(func.first('oil').alias('oil'), 
        func.first('gas').alias('gas')
        ). \
    show()

# +---+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
# | id|month|q1 2023_oil|q1 2023_gas|q2 2023_oil|q2 2023_gas|q3 2023_oil|q3 2023_gas|q4 2023_oil|q4 2023_gas|
# +---+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
# |  1|    1|          5|         10|       null|       null|       null|       null|       null|       null|
# |  2|    2|         20|         30|       null|       null|       null|       null|       null|       null|
# +---+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```